# vscodeでcmd+home/endが効かない

Tags: macos, vscode

macのvscodeで <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>home/end</kbd> が効かないのですが、どういう理由なのか教えていただけますでしょうか。

規定のキーバンドを見ると以下の様になっており設定は問題なさそうですが、なぜか作動しません。

```
{ "key": "cmd+home",              "command": "workbench.action.terminal.scrollToTop",
                                     "when": "terminalFocus" },
```

また、<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> でコマンドパレットを開き "key" と入力すると

- キーボードショートカットの設定
- キーボードショートカットの設定（JSON)
- 規定のキーボードショートカットの設定（JSON)

の３項目表示されますが、これらはどう違うのでしょうか？